# Creating pandas dataframe from huge list/array (size >20million rows)? Way too slow! Any workaround? Or alternative?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I have always used pandas for my data manipulation/visualization purposes. The size of my data, up to now, was not that large, so I never had a noticeable computational performance issue. I am now working, for the first time, with way larger datasets (lists/arrays with >20million rows and a large number of features,) and pandas/memory is a bottleneck.

Since I am new to large/big data, I would like to ask if there is any workaround for this so I can still be able to use pandas and not overload memory. Otherwise, any suggestions or alternatives that might be worth checking out?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [dask](https://dask.org/). A project where some of the `pandas` developers are working on as well

Comment: Thanks, Erfan! Will have a look at dask. Looks very promising.